# Delete database columns that have NaN values in the last row

Tags: python, pandas

I am using python and pandas to store a monthly database with ETF prices dates.

First column is the date (and also the index) and all following columns refer to funds codes.

I am trying to delete all columns that have NaN values in the last row (funds that are already closed) to reduce the size of the database, but I am doing it by hand (one by one).

Is there a piece of code that can help me to automatize that?

thanks! :)

Database as follows:

```
            00.068.305/0001-35  ...  97.543.707/0001-86
DT_COMPTC                       ...                    
2017-01-31           23.068765  ...                 NaN
2017-02-28           23.251754  ...                 NaN
2017-03-31           23.477918  ...                 NaN
2020-01-31           27.181630  ...                 NaN
2020-02-28           27.234258  ...                 NaN
2020-03-31           27.258097  ...                 NaN
2020-04-30           27.172798  ...                 NaN
```

Comment: _Is there a piece of code that can help me to automatize that?_ Almost certainly, yes. Please see [ask], [help/on-topic]. Also, you wrote _last row_, but did you mean the last column?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**df:**

```
    Ip  Id  cat prob
0   1   ll  0.2 0.10
1   1   ll  1.0 0.45
2   1   12  0.5 NaN
3   2   11  0.3 NaN
4   2   12  0.5 NaN
5   3   10  0.7 0.30
6   3   10  0.5 0.50
7   3   NaN 0.2 NaN
```

---

```
x = df.iloc[[-1]].isnull()
```

---

**x:**

```
    Ip      Id      cat     prob
7   False   True    False   True
```

---

```
y = df.columns[x.iloc[0]]
```

---

**y:**

```
Index(['Id', 'prob'], dtype='object')
```

You can now drop the column by using

```
df.drop(y, axis=1, inplace=True)
```

---

**df:**

```
Ip  cat
0   1   0.2
1   1   1.0
2   1   0.5
3   2   0.3
4   2   0.5
5   3   0.7
6   3   0.5
7   3   0.2
```

Comment: Why downvote? Please whosoever downvoted give the feedback why they downvoted so that answer can be improved.